# Matrix Field Slug Output

Tags: matrix, craft3, slug

I am not sure why, but I cannot seem to get the short name/handle/slug of a matrix field that is a category field.  I need to get it's slug.

```
{% for row in entry.matrixField %}

 {{ row.matrixChild.slug }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just a side note: looping through `Queries` is deprecated. You should take a look into your deprecator logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is returning an `ElementQuery`. I'm assuming you only need to get the first category. You need to use `.one` to get the category element.

```
{% for row in entry.matrixField.all() %}
    {{ row.matrixChild.one.slug }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you wish to display more than one category you can use a `{% nav %}` or `{% for %}` to loop through them. See the [category docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/categories-fields.html).

Comment: Thanks Simon!  I had a few of those fields empty and I got an error so I added {% if row.matrixChild.one|length %} around it and it works :)

Comment: You're welcome. Adding `|length` is exactly what I would do too.